# how to run multiple data set as parameter for testcase on cypress in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, cypress, typescript2.0

I would like to run testcase with multiple data fixtures that is build by object of array on Cypress. As following, 
I have error as **TS2345: Argument of type '(fixture: { name: string; sValue: string; eValue: string}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { name: string; sValue: string; eValue: string}, index: number, array: { name: string; sValue: string; eValue: string; }[]) => void'.** anyone know why?, what do I do wrong?

```
const Fixtures = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    sValue: 'a',
    eValue: '1',
  },

  {
    name: 'name2',
    sValue: 'b',
    eValue: '2',
  },
];
Fixtures.forEach(
  (fixture: {
    name: string;
    sValue: string;
    eValue: string;
  }) => {
    describe(`${fixture.name} test`, () => {
      it(`set value ${fixture.sValue}`, () => {
        ...
      });

      it(`check ${fixture.name} on ${fixture.sValue}`, () => {
        ...
      });

      it('check test4', () => {
        ...
      });

      it('check testcase 5', () => {
        ...
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: `forEach()` has a signature with 3 params, `(value, index, array)`. It may be a fault in the type definition, but looks like it's expecting all 3 to be specified. You can probably just type those to any `(fixture: {...}, index: any, array: any[]) =>`.

Comment: Even my fixture is object I need to do that? Or I can ignore put in type

Answer (score 0):

```
Fixtures.forEach((fixture) => {
describe(`${fixture.name} test`, () => {
  it(`set value ${fixture.sValue}`, () => {
    ...
  });
```

});

Try above. As I understand you don't need to initialize the object again inside foreach.